# Add to configmap pod name in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I'm trying to figure it out, how to change one string inside configmap in Kubernetes. I have pretty simple configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.cfg: |-
    [authentication]
    USERNAME=user
    PASSWORD=password
     
    [podname]
    PODNAME=metadata.podName

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: name_here
```

And I need to mount the configmap inside a couple of pods. But PODNAME should be matched to current podname. Is it possible in any another way? thanks!

Comment: Use [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it could be done with ConfigMap. But you can set environment variables in your pod spec that references a pod fields.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-ref-pod-name
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - env | grep PODNAME
      env:
        - name: PODNAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
  restartPolicy: Never
```

See official documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables

Comment: This is nice but it will not work with pod names generated from a deployment or stateful set. Such pods follow the pattern <depoyment name>-<hash of metadata>-<random 5 characters>.

Comment: thanks! I saw that option, but the issue is - I need this file config.cfg mounted to the app folder

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer you question exactly but the pod name normally ends up as the host name inside the pod and can be accessed as a standard environment variable

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```